# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around variable

Tags: c, exception, c-strings, runtimeexception

I have the next code with the error -"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'action' was corrupted."

```
bool playerTurn(char board[][22], char boardcover[][22], int rows, int cols)
    
{
        char action[1];
        int row, col, count = 0;
    
        printf("please enter your move, row and column: ");
        scanf("%d%d", &row, &col);
        scanf("%s", action);
    
        if (action[0] == 'F') {
            boardcover[row][col] = 'F';
        }
    
        if (action[0] == 'O') {
            boardcover[row][col] = board[row][col];
            revealCell(board, boardcover, rows, cols, row, col);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What can be the problem?

I tried to initialize the 'action' and to scan only char but everything is not the right solution and I still have the exception.

Comment: The `char action[1];` array isn't big enough to hold both an input character *and* the (required) `nul` terminator. Needs to be (at least) `char action[2];`.

Comment: Hello. Can you tell me the `makefile` flag to turn on the run time check? I've lost my `makefile` configuration for that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'action' was corrupted." usually occurs after a buffer overflow.

First: `char action[1]`: this variable can hold string of a maximum size of 0, yes you've read well. In C strings are NUL terminated (details are in the chapter dealing with strings in your beginner's C text book). So if you enter any string longer than 0 chars, the `action` buffer overflows hence the error message.

Second: with `scanf("%s", action)` no check of buffer size is done, so if you declare `char action[10]`, and you enter a string longer than 9 chars (Q: why 9 and not 10? A: remmber the NUL terminator) you' get a buffer overflow.

So what you should do is to use `scanf("%9s", action)` which will limit the size of the string entered to 9 chars.

---

But actually as you want to input only *one* character you can simply use a char instead of a string:

```
char action;           // declare one single char
...
scanf("%c", &action);  // use %c instead of %s
...
```